# Color confinement vs. Weak charge confinement

Tags: gauge-theory, quantum-chromodynamics, electroweak, confinement

Sometimes, color confinement is explained loosely by stating that the gauge group of QCD, namely SU(3), is non-abelian gauge group and, therefore, tends to form narrow "flux tubes" through which the "efective force" does not decrease with distance.

However, this absolutely informal explanation leaves out **the key factor** (whatever would be). Since, for example, the Weinberg–Salam theory (WST) describing weak interaction is also based on a gauge theory with the non-abelian group SU(2), one would think that it should also form narrow flux tubes, that would prevent any "weak charge" from being observed unconfined.

My question is: What is the ingredient that makes QCD lead to color confinement, but WST does not entail weak charge confinement?

Comment: Related https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/38982/weak-isospin-confinement

Comment: [Linked near duplicate](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/713546/are-there-physical-fields-in-non-abelian-gauge-theories).

Comment: You may, and do, understand *both* weak and strong interactions in terms of a non-singlet state description and a singlet state description, above a characteristic scale and below it, respectively. For the strong interactions, the scale is a fraction of a GeV, Λ; for the weak ones, once you appreciate Susskind's complementarity, touched upon in the linked question, it is a quarter of a TeV.